# Trying to combine the columns for a case function

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql

This was the original question.

3. Retrieve shipping status
   You have been asked to create a query that returns a list of sales order IDs and order dates with a column named ShippingStatus that contains the text “Shipped” for orders with a known ship date, and “Awaiting Shipment” for orders with no ship date.

   ```
   SELECT SalesOrderID, ShipDate,
       CASE   
           WHEN ShipDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Shipped'
           ELSE 'Awaiting Shipment'
       END AS 'Shipping Status'
   FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader;
   ```

The following case function returned the correct information but returned 3 columns, SalesOrderID, ShipDate, and Shipping Status.

[image: See the Sql Query Result here]

Trying to figure out what I can do to merge these into 2 columns instead of three.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The question is asking for three columns.  Why would you want to merge them into two?  Admittedly, you are returning the ship date rather than the order date, but that is a question of what data is in the columns, not how many there are.

Comment: Tip: As a rule, the `mysql` and `tsql` tags are incompatible. (Hover over them for details.) Do you really require a solution that works for multiple databases? It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is the question not asking for 2 columns? SalesOrderID and a column with whether the items were shipped or awaiting shipment?

What I wanted to query was two columns, return "Shipped" if "Shipdate" is present and "Awaiting Shipment if the cell is null/empty.  In this case, I only want column 1 & 3.

Comment: @asirris . . . "that returns a list of sales order IDs and order dates with a column named ShippingStatus".  This sounds like three columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right! I think I had this, I also didn't realize the case funtion is querying a different column. What I was thinking was that it was checking ShippingDate and if there was date in that cell, return "Shipped" or Return Awaiting Shipment.  Almost like IS NOT NILL, Return Shipped, if NULL Returned Waiting Shipment. I'm checking the answer key to see what they had. Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the question does indeed appear to be asking for a result with 3 columns (Sales Order ID, Order Date, Shipping Status):

```
SELECT 
    SalesOrderID, 
    OrderDate,
    CASE   
        WHEN ShipDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Shipped'
        ELSE 'Awaiting Shipment'
    END AS [Shipping Status]
FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader;
```

I am making an assumption here that the Order Date column is called `OrderDate`, as this is not specified in your question.

If you did just want to show the Sales Order ID and Shipping Status, just omit the second column entirely:

```
SELECT 
    SalesOrderID, 
    CASE   
        WHEN ShipDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Shipped'
        ELSE 'Awaiting Shipment'
    END AS [Shipping Status]
FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader;
```